# URL Validation (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I am trying to validate a URL with this method:

Code:

```
- (BOOL) validateUrl: (NSString *) candidate {

    NSString *urlRegEx=
    @"((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|notes|ms-help):((//)|(\\\\))+[\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&]*)";

    NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx]; 
    return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];

}
```

It does not function. I think the problem is with the regular expression.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`+ (id)URLWithString:(NSString *)URLString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/URLWithString:) method of `NSURL`, which returns `nil` if the string is malformed.

Use `if (URL && URL.scheme && URL.host)` for checking URL.

Comment: i tried it! but still it does not work ! for example "ht://www.yahoo." this works well ! and it does not return nill !!!

Comment: This is valid URl according to RFC 2396.From apple documentation The string with which to initialize the NSURL object. Must be a URL that conforms to RFC 2396. This method parses URLString according to RFCs 1738 and 1808. use "if (URL && URL.scheme && URL.host)" for checking URL.

Comment: RFC 2396 uses this ^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))? regular expression. For more information refer http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt

Comment: I'd do what what's suggested here and then match `[url scheme]` against a scheme whitelist.

Comment: This is false! `[NSURL urlWithString:]` will return a non-nil URL regardless of the string passed. Try  `[NSURL urlWithString:@"foo"]` if you're not convinced.

Comment: @SamBallantyne Read my all comments.

Comment: @ParagBafna The `URLWithString:` method of NSURL does not return nil if the string is "malformed".

Comment: @SamBallantyne From apple documentation : "return value:  If the URL string was malformed or nil, returns nil."

Answer (score 6):

Try with this..

```
- (BOOL) validateUrl: (NSString *) candidate {
    NSString *urlRegEx =
    @"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
    NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx]; 
    return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

it may help u out.

Answer (score 1):

## What about using the following:

NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];

BOOL isValid = [UIApplication.sharedApplication canOpenURL:url];

## note: best practice is to use regex

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *urlRegEx = @"http(s)?://([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+(/[\\w- ./?%&amp;=]*)?";
```

Comment: Not the best regex. For example, doesn't work with Https://google.com because of the capital "H," even though this is a valid URL.